# How to instruct the app module to override a resource in a dependency module?

Tags: android, dependencies, android-resources, modularity

I know that putting an asset, let's say an svg icon in one of the dependencies and putting another icon with the same name in the main app module, when it comes to using the resource the app would always use the resource in the app module over the dependency resource.

The problem am facing is as follows:
I have the main app module that depends on three different modules, let's say A, B and C. When putting the resource in A and the main app module, the behavior is normal, when using the resource the one in the app module emerge.
But when doing the same with B and C and trying to use the resource, the resource in the dependencies emerge.

Any help ?

Comment: A B C are all library modules? or B C are app modules?

Comment: @navylover A, B and C are library modules yes

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue, and as official docs said: If a given resource ID is defined in both modules, the resource from the app is used

Comment: @navylover please check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after many trials, it seems like the problem was in the build.gradle of the modules B and C
I added `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` as I found it added in module A which behaves normally and everything worked as expected.
I cannot understand how it's related, if any one have an explanation please enlight me.